# Negating the first occurrence of specific String using Regular Expression in java.

Tags: java, regex

In the code attached, I am trying to modify **String toParse = "love love koo love love koo";** and get the output

> Result love love    Result love love

But the pattern I am using

> love[^koo]*

will give me the output Result

> Result love l Result love l

**ie on the very first occurrence of 'k' or 'o' its splitting**, 
but my intention is on very first **occurrence of "koo"** it has to split, so that I will get the desired result. In short my intention is to create a pattern that will find till the first occurrence of **"koo".**

I have also attached my java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // regular expression here
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("love[^koo]*");
    // String here
    String toParse = "love love koo love love koo";

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toParse);

    boolean found = false;
    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.println("Result "
                + toParse.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
        found = true;
    }
    if (!found) {
        // console.format("No match found.%n");
        System.out.println("No match found");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right and you want to get everything until koo, your regex should be:

```
"(.+?)koo"
```

Your result is in the group(1)

```
while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Result "+ matcher.group(1));
        found = true;
}
```

Comment: yeah this will find everythig to **koo** , but what I want is contents between love to first occurence of koo.  Suppose my toParse="love cow koo cow cow koo". I want the result as "love cow". ie **any content between love to the first occurence of koo, including love**.

Comment: @user2118591 how about this? `(love.*?)koo`

Comment: but that will include koo in the result. koo should be negated.

Comment: @user2118591 have you tried my code or you are just assuming that?

Comment: I just now tried. In my code I replaaced my pattern with yours, the result had "koo" in it

Comment: @Livejava and how about replacing the while loop as suggested?

Comment: I need the loop, because I have to find all the occurrence in the string.

Comment: @Livejava This is what regex is for. Just modify it as I suggested and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, split...

```
    String str = "love love koo love love koo";
    for (String s : str.split("koo *")) {
        System.out.print("Result " + s);
    }
```